# Asus NT-R56U wiress router and VoIP device

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, voip

The problems are

- I cannot log onto my wireless router
- When both are connected, it doesn't work.  When only one of VoIP and router are connected, it works beautifully

The configuration looks like this

--[Cable Modem]--[Cisco SPA122 VoIP]--[Asus RT-N56U Wireless Router]--[Computer]

On the surface of the router, it tells me

192.168.1.1

and log onto the router with login : admin password : admin

But when I enter 192.168.1.1 I get nothing.

When I enter 192.168.18.1 it does prompt me for a login and a password but admin / admin does not work

Thank you, experts on Super User!

The exact message I get is

**The server http://192.168.18.1 requires a username and password. The server says : RT-N56U :**

I can use the Internet for now, but I need to update the firmware and possibly change the password and SSID

Should I simply reset the entire router? If that's the only option it will be my pleasure to do so.

I was able to log onto my VoIP device using 192.168.15.1 successfully and update the firmware perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason the ASUS displays 192.168.1.1 is because that's the factory default. If that has changed, which it has in your case, then you use the modified address.

If the default login credentials, admin/admin do not work, clearly they are no longer the default.

I could get info on the ASUS to see if it supports different modes. like the AC line does (router, WAP, streaming). In the past when you had a wireless router but also had a router in front of it, as you do with your Cisco box, we would disable DHCP on the device and plug the cable from either the LAN port or a switch port to the wireless router's switch port and not the WAN or Internet port. This way the wireless router works as a WAP and not a router.

However, if you need to disable DHCP on the wireless router, then you need access and you will have to do a factory reset. Since you can get into the Cisco box, make sure DHCP is enabled.  By default, your ASUS will connect it's WAN port via DHCP but if you're only using it as a WAP, then there is no sense is routing twice. If you have a router behind a router, it's because you desire to segment traffic.

Comment: I just ended up resetting and all were fixed in less than a minute with the latest firmware installed.

Comment: Well done. Always good to hear when issues have been resolved.